# what does $f '(x^2)$ mean?

Tags: functions, derivatives

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QISCU.png)what does $f '(x^2)$ mean? does it mean calculating $f '(x)$ and then putting x=x² or first putting $x=x^2$ in $f(x)$ and then differentiating it?

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and $f'(x)=g(x)$
So $g(x)=3x^2$

$g(x^2)= 3x^4$

$f'(x^2)=3x^4$ how this is incorrect?

Comment: I have answered, but not in full... Just the information required...

Comment: @TheBroly you are correct

Comment: It means:  take the derivative of $f$ and evaluate it at $x^2$, just as you have written.

Comment: f(x^2) = x^6 , f '(x^2) =6x^5 I am confused , which one is correct

Comment: dont substitute $x$ by $x^2$ in $f(x)$!

Comment: i have an image , how to show this in comment?

Comment: @TheBroly put it in your post, not in a comment

Comment: I have posted image. Shouldn't here y'=f '(2x-1/x^2+1) ?If it is so?

Comment: @TheBroly it is. $y'=f'()$ and then derivative of whats in $()$

Comment: @TheBroly see that they substitute $f'()$ with $\sin ()^2$

Comment: for eg: if $y=f(x^4)$ then, $y'=f'(x^4)\cdot 4x^3$ i.e. derivative of $f(x^4)$ multiplied by derivative of $x^4$

Comment: f(x^2) = x^6 , f '(x^2) =6x^5 how it is incorrect? Is it f'(x^2).(2x)=(3x^4)(2x)=6x^5?

Comment: your case is different. you want $f'(x^2)$, not derivative of $f(x^2)$.  so just put $x=x^2$ in $f'(x)$, giving you $3x^4$

Comment: Thanks ,Now I understand f′(x^2) is not derivative of f(x^2)

Comment: yes! if $y=f(x^2)$ den $y'=f'(x^2)\cdot 2x$

Comment: if you want $f'(x^2)$ you need to replace $x^2$ by $t$ and take $2xdx=dt$

Comment: Proof:   $f(x^2)=x^6=f(t)=t^3$ and $2xdx=dt$. $f'(t)=3t^2dt$ So, $f'(x^2)=3x^4(2x)=6x^5$ which you got, and mistook it for $f'(x^2)$

Comment: Yes, I mistaken between f '(x^2) and (f(x^2))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

DON'T substitute $x=x^2$ in $f(x)$.
 $$f(x)=x^3$$
Take first derivative:
$$f'(x)=3x^2$$
 Replace $x$ by $x^2$ $$f'(x^2)=3(x^2)^2=3x^4$$
This is how you find value of $f'(x)$ for ANY $x$; just replace $x$ by that.
Who told you $3x^4$ is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of $h(x)=f(x^2)$ should be denoted $h'(x)=\bigl(f(x^2)\bigr)'$, whereas $f'(x^2)$ is the derivative of $f$, evaluated at $x^2$. So your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x^2)$ means

1. find the derivative of $f(x)$. $f'(x)=g(x)$
2. evaluate the derivate at point $x^2$. $f'(x^2)=g(x^2)$